# Radio base station location in Italy

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uses-of-open-data

Are there any datasets or websites that have the location data of cellular/radio base station in Milan, Italy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out OpenCelliD, https://www.opencellid.org/.

> OpenCelliD aims to document all Cell Towers and WiFi APs around the world along with their locations.